# WMI: Win32_DiskDrive to get total sector on the physical disk drive

Tags: python, winapi, wmi, disk, pywin32

I have tried getting the maximum total sector of a disk using [Win32_DiskDrive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394132%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but all of them return the incorrect value. I used [HxD](http://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/) and this program return the accurate value. I've tried to get the total sector in Linux using fdisk, it also return accurately.

I notice that there's a Note in the [Win32_DiskDrive MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394132%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) as follow:

> the value for this property is obtained through extended functions of BIOS interrupt 13h. The value may be inaccurate if the drive uses a translation scheme to support high-capacity disk sizes. Consult the manufacturer for accurate drive specifications.

But I couldn't understand what it means? and how to resolve this issue?

### Update 1:

Here's a snip code of my python script.

Required: [Python](http://python.org/download/), [PyWin32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/), [WMI](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/WMI/#downloads)

```
import wmi

c = wmi.WMI()
for diskDrive in c.query("SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive"):
    print diskDrive.Name, "\nTotal Sector: ", diskDrive.TotalSectors
```

### Update 2:

As requested, here's the Snippet of WMI with HxD total sector detected.

- **WMI:** 625137345 (Top)
- **HxD:** 625142448 (Bottom)

[image: Sector Difference Screenshot]

### Update 3:

If anyone interested, you can also try this on your own computer and see whether the Win32_DiskDrive report the accurate result. I tried this on many other computer *(WinXP & 7)* with other storage device *(Hard disk, Flash Disk, etc.)*, but the all of the result is inaccurate.

To try please install [Python](http://python.org/download/), [PyWin32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/), [WMI](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/WMI/#downloads)

**Thank you very much**

Comment: The note which you refear not mention the `BytesPerSector` property of the [Win32_DiskDrive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394132%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) WMI class, so from where you get that info?

Comment: @RRUZ Sorry, I just fixed my question, what I meant is not the sector size, but the "total sector" instead.

Comment: Where's your code? what platform(s) exactly are you trying to do this on?

Comment: @ChibuezeOpata: I've updated my question to provide some snip code.

Answer (score 3):

WMI reports the drives a few MB smaller than they actually are. I think it has to do with how Windows treats the drive in terms of cylinders/heads/sectors.

My solution was to read past the end of the reported drive size until I get an error:

```
import wmi
disks = wmi.WMI().Win32_DiskDrive(MediaType="Removable Media")
for disk in disks:
    disk_size = int(disk.size)
    sector_size = disk.BytesPerSector
    print(disk.name, "reported size:", disk_size)
    with open(disk.name, "rb") as f:
        f.seek(disk_size)
        while True:
            try:
                f.read(sector_size)
                disk_size += sector_size
            except PermissionError:
                break
    print(disk.name, "readable size:", disk_size)
```

I get the following result for two different 32GB SD Cards:

```
\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE2 reported size: 31683778560
\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE2 readable size: 31691110400
\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE3 reported size: 31437020160
\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE3 readable size: 31439453184
```

However, the actual drives actually have an additional 1024 to 2048 bytes that we still can't read, and I'm not sure how to get them. However, this is better than a few MB that we were missing before.

**Edit:** Seems like the [buffering](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/io.html#io.DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE) was causing the problem with reading the last few bytes. I can read the remaining bytes if I do `open(disk.name, "rb", buffering=0)`. However, this was very slow (~1MB/second, which equals around 7 seconds for one of the drives). There's probably a good hybrid approach where you only use buffering=0 to read the last few bytes, and you use the default buffering the rest of the time.

```
\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE2 reported size: 31683778560
\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE2 readable size: 31691112448 (with buffering=0)
\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE14 reported size: 31437020160
\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE14 readable size: 31439454208 (with buffering=0)
```

**Edit 2:** You can get the last few bytes by using `read1`, without needing to open the file with `buffering=0`. So to get the actual disk size, you can do this:

```
reported_size = disk.size
f.seek(reported_size)
while True:
    try:  # Read beyond the reported size
        f.read(sector_size)
    except PermissionError:
        easily_readable_size = f.tell()
        try:  # Get the last few bytes using read1 (unbuffered)
            for i in range(128):  # Test up to this many additional sectors
                f.read1(self.sector_size)
        except PermissionError:
            actual_size = f.tell()
            break
```

Note I *think* that you might not always be able to `f.read` up to `easily_readable_size` since the alignment of the internal buffers might not always be the same(?). I reduced that value by `io.DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE` to be a little safer. Then I overwrote `f.read` with my own function that does a combination of the above stuff to transparently `f.read` correctly across the whole disk. That way, `f.read` works how you would expect it to work in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

I had problems using the read test solution of user **user3268002**. With a working USB flash drive it caused a freeze of exactly one minute, also made drive lists inaccessable from other apps during that time and once even caused the drive to become not accessible anymore until replugged. The reported size was also incorrect depending on the initial seek position, reporting too much bytes (sectors) because the first read() call happily read a few sectors beyond the end without an exception. It works with normal hard disks though.

The following code gave me always the correct size as reported by **HxD** for all tested drives.

```
import struct
import win32file  #pip install pywin32
import winioctlcon #pip install pywin32

f = win32file.CreateFile('\\\\.\\PHYSICALDRIVE0', win32file.GENERIC_READ, 0, None, win32file.OPEN_EXISTING, win32file.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0)
size = win32file.DeviceIoControl(f, winioctlcon.IOCTL_DISK_GET_LENGTH_INFO, None, 512, None)  #returns bytes
size = struct.unpack('q', size)[0]  #convert 64 bit int from bytes to int -> first element of returned tuple
print(size)
f.close()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: I would use `win32file.GENERIC_READ, win32file.FILE_SHARE_READ | win32file.FILE_SHARE_WRITE, None` in place of `win32file.GENERIC_READ, 0, None`. Otherwise other processes cannot access the '\\\\.\\PHYSICALDRIVE0' object at the same time. Also, it appears from my experiments that if Python would quit before it closes the handle then you would be unable to open it again in another Python process for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

You speak like this snippet does not work for a particular HDD? Can you give us the details of this hard disk and how you know it's incorrect.

However, try using pure winapi approach instead. The `DeviceIoControl` can be used to do this *comfortably*. See a [complete code listing](http://www.winsim.com/diskid32/diskid32.cpp) in cpp.

I know there's a way to write c++ in python so goodluck :)

Comment: The snippet worked for any HDD, only that the result is less than the result from HxD application. HxD detects more sector than what WinAPI detected. 

Originally, I came from the C programming language to do the `DeviceIoControl`, but the result also less. I then try WMI using Python, the result also less.

I tried to run on another machine with different disk, and the result using this WinAPI always less than what HxD Detect.

Comment: WINAPI should provide the best accuracy as far as I know. Other possibilities could be that your disk is misbehaving or that HxD is wrong. Can you post the different value sizes you're getting here?

Comment: I've just uploaded the screenshot in the question update 2. You're correct WINAPI is always provide the best accuracy. But in the [Win32_DiskDrive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394132(v=vs.85).aspx), there is a note said that. `The value may be inaccurate if the drive uses a translation scheme to support high-capacity disk sizes.`. I don't quite get it what this note means. How to solve this. Why HxD can detect the correct value..

Comment: You didn't add what the WINAPI returns?

Comment: The Win32_DiskDrive return me all the information about the [DiskDrive property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394132(v=vs.85).aspx). So I just access its property (SectorSize). Sorry if I misunderstood as I don't get what you mean by WINAPI Returns

Comment: I mean you should use the code sample above which implements DeviceIoControl. After implementing, post result here.